# gcloud error 500 on strapi deployment (EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/srv/.tmp' A )

Tags: postgresql, gcloud, strapi

I followed strap's guide to an google app engine deployment however when I pushed it to gcloud I get an error 500. It's on postgresql, Standard Environment. I don't know what other informations to include. Here's the error from gcloud.

```
    2020-07-11T21:37:04.742759Z     at DatabaseManager.initialize (/srv/node_modules/strapi-database/lib/database-manager.js:36:27) A 
2020-07-11T21:37:04.742769Z     at Strapi.load (/srv/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:274:19) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:09.103534Z GET 500 0 B 11.3 s Chrome 83 / I GET 500 0 B 11.3 s Chrome 83 5f0a353d00ff01946e3ca1b9ce0001737e736b756c70740001323032303037313174313635323139000100
2020-07-11T21:55:19.559829Z [2020-07-11T21:55:19.558Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly. A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.562896Z [2020-07-11T21:55:19.562Z] error Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/srv/.tmp' A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.562935Z     at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:757:3) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.562956Z     at _.forEach (/srv/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/knex.js:152:16) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.562972Z     at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15 A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.562987Z     at baseForOwn (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.563012Z     at /srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4894:18 A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.563025Z     at Function.forEach (/srv/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9368:14) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.563034Z     at module.exports.strapi (/srv/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/knex.js:37:5) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.563043Z     at Object.initialize (/srv/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/index.js:39:5) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.563058Z     at Object.initialize (/srv/node_modules/strapi-database/lib/connector-registry.js:30:25) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.563071Z     at DatabaseManager.initialize (/srv/node_modules/strapi-database/lib/database-manager.js:36:27) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:19.563080Z     at Strapi.load (/srv/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:274:19) A 
2020-07-11T21:55:20.688345Z GET 500 0 B 4.5 s Chrome 83 /favicon.ico I GET 500 0 B 4.5 s Chrome 83 5f0a354800ff0a80d9edd664c60001737e736b756c70740001323032303037313174313635323139000100
```

I tried launching it multiple times but same error. All of the postgresql information are correct as well. What is causing this?

**Edit:**

this is the instructions that I followed. https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/google-app-engine.html

I got up to deploy the project with `gcloud app deploy`

[image: vi]

Comment: If you could provide the link to the documentation you followed and at which step you have stopped, it's better, so the Community can try to replicate your issue and verify what might be causing it. Besides that, more information, such as the versions you are using, are beneficial as well.

Comment: I updated it and provided more information on there.